# CMakeLists pkg-config opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made program with "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp" like this include.

```
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
```

When I compile the program, I need some option like this.

```
g++ filename.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

These are no error. But I don't know how to write this on CMakeLists.

When I do catkin_make, these are same error that I compiled without option.

Please tell me.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250732/cmakelists-pkg-config-opencv-c++/) by [sora](https://answers.ros.org/users/28523/sora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quick google search for "cmake opencv" turns up: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html

Following the example there, it looks like you need to add the following to your CMakeLists:

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
```

And then link to OpenCV with:

```
target_link_libraries( your_executable ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sora](https://answers.ros.org/users/28523/sora/) on 2016-12-27**:
I thought these are no link of nonfree in OpenCV.

But, I can solve it by your advice.

thanks